# Multiple divs that trigger single overlay

Tags: jquery

I am making a portfolio and would like to trigger an overlay that covers the size of the div when the "read more" button is clicked.

I tried writing some simple jQuery.  I tried using "this" in jQuery but my overlays stopped working correctly.  I'm assuming I used "this" incorrectly.

This is my code:

```
   <div class="item">
      <div id="outer-box">
          <div class="test-image"></div>
          <div id="inner-box" class="js-project_overlay">
              <p>This is the overlay!</p>
              <div class="close js_close">Close</div>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="read-more js-click-overlay">Read More</div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <div id="outer-box">
          <div class="test-image"></div>
          <div id="inner-box" class="js-project_overlay">
              <p>This is the overlay!</p>
              <div class="close js_close">Close</div>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="read-more js-click-overlay">Read More</div>
   </div>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
    $(".js-click-overlay").click(function() {
          $(".js-project_overlay").addClass("js-project_overlay_open");
    });

$(".js_close").click(function() {
          $(".js-project_overlay").removeClass("js-project_overlay_open");
    });
```

Actual results:  When I click on "Read More", all the overlays open.

Expected results: I only want the overlay for that particular project to display when clicking that "Read More" button.

Comment: Can you include your CSS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parents()` to traverse the HTML upwards and then find the relevant elements, like so:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".js-click-overlay").click(function() {
        // traverse upwards to find .item then find the project overlay
        $(this).parents(".item").find(".js-project_overlay").addClass("js-project_overlay_open");
    });

    $(".js_close").click(function() {
        // traverse upwards again to find the project overlay then close it
        $(this).parents(".js-project_overlay").removeClass("js-project_overlay_open");
    });
})
```

```css
.js-project_overlay_open {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <!-- outer-box changed from "id" to "class" -->
    <div class="outer-box">
        <div class="test-image"></div>

        <!-- inner-box also changed from "id" to "class" -->
        <div class="inner-box js-project_overlay">
            <p>This is the overlay!</p>
            <div class="close js_close">Close</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="read-more js-click-overlay">Read More</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="outer-box">
        <div class="test-image"></div>
        <div class="inner-box js-project_overlay">
            <p>This is the overlay!</p>
            <div class="close js_close">Close</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="read-more js-click-overlay">Read More</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I removed the duplicate `id` attributes in your HTML as that's invalid markup.

Comment: This looks about right but the only thing is, I need to add the "js-project_overlay_open" class to a specific class "js-project_overlay" and still use "this".  What does that syntax look like?